# CATextLayer font size animation velocity

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a little annoying problem. I have a CATextLayer, which I use to display the placeholder of UITextView. The fact is that when animating this layer, its velocity is too small and I see "jumps" during the animation. I use UIView.animate with a velocity parameter, but it ignores it.

[GIF FILE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK0xe.gif)

[image]

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.2,
        delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
        initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, // Ignore any options
        options: .curveEaseOut,
        animations: {
            self.floatingLabel?.fontSize = 10
            self.floatingLabel?.frame = self.toggledFloaterFrame
        })
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Animation of the `fontSize` property is not possible. Try using the `transform` to scale it down.

You can use `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)` with `scale` being `10/self.floatingLabel.fontSize` and `CGAffineTransform.identity` to go back to full size.

Comment: CATextLayer property fontSize is animatable, check the gif

Comment: @ДимитрийПоляков I extracted the 3 movements of your text in the label. The font Size does not "animate". It jumps each time it gets a size smaller. http://imgur.com/a/kSiz0

Comment: Ok, i see it now. CGAffineTransform helped, thanks. I found in the documentation that animation available only for macos

Comment: This is incorrect. `fontSize` is very much an animatable property on `CATextLayer`. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catextlayer/1515290-fontsize